# Linked List error assigning temp variable to first variable of list

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I have been working with linked lists and I am trying to assign temp variable to the first node in the list but it errors out

code where I set a temp node to list

```
Node *temp = NULL;
Node *found = NULL;
bool isfound = false;

temp = list;
```

the place where list defined in LinkedList class

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#include "Node.h"


class LinkedList{

private:

Node *list; 
Node *createNode();
Node *searchLocation(int);
public:
LinkedList();
~LinkedList();
void insertNode();
void deleteNode(int);
void printList();
void searchNode();

};
```

#endif

node header

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

class Node{
public:
char lastName[20];
char firstName[20];
int idNumber;
Node *next;
Node *head;

Node(char a[], char b[], int i);
void printNode();

};

#endif
```

node class

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "Node.h"
 using namespace std;
 Node::Node(char a[], char b[], int i){

 *lastName = *a;
 *firstName = *b;
 idNumber = i;

 }

 void Node::printNode(){

 cout<<lastName<<", "<<firstName<<": "<<idNumber<<endl;

 }
```

error says can't convert from LinkedList* to Node* in assignment temp = list;

Comment: Doesn't that error tell you everything you need to know? You are trying to assigna a `LinkedList*` to a `Node*`. Your code (which you haven't shown) is wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  I don't understand what the question is.  The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: the question is why is list not a node here and how can I get the first member of list.

Comment: ok i put the rest in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown where you declare the list object, but from the error I can see it is of type LinkedList*.
If you want to point to the first node, then you have to assign
  temp = list->list.

Of course since list is a private member of LinkedList, you cannot do this outside of the LinkedList class.
So you need to provide an accessor function that returns this node object.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that list is a LinkedList *, then `temp = list->list;` should work.

Comment: naw, it's list is private.